# Add search and sort functionality to VuetifyJS list with VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, search, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to add a simple search and sort functionality to a [VuetifyJS list](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#example-title-subtitle-actions-and-action-text). 
Here is a CodePen example of the list: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxGGgv

What is the standard way to do this in VueJS 2?

**HTML:**

```
<v-list two-line>
  <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <v-list-tile
        :key="item.title"
        avatar
        ripple
        @click="toggle(index)"
      >
        <v-list-tile-content>
           <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
           <v-list-tile-sub-title class="text--primary">
               {{ item.headline }}
           </v-list-tile-sub-title>
           <v-list-tile-sub-title>{{ item.subtitle }}</v-list-tile-sub-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>
      <v-divider
        v-if="index + 1 < items.length"
        :key="index"
      ></v-divider>
  </template>
</v-list>
```

JS:

```
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        selected: [2],
        items: [
          {
            action: '15 min',
            headline: 'Brunch this weekend?',
            title: 'Ali Connors',
            subtitle: "I'll be in your neighborhood doing errands this weekend. Do you want to hang out?"
          },
          {
            action: '18hr',
            headline: 'Recipe to try',
            title: 'Britta Holt',
            subtitle: 'We should eat this: Grate, Squash, Corn, and tomatillo Tacos.'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a computed property in your class and do your filters. You can use this computed property as your **filtering** and **sorting** function.

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/prc0mputing/pen/qMBLNr?editors=1010)

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selected: [2],
        search: '',
        items: [{
                action: '15 min',
                headline: 'Brunch this weekend?',
                title: 'Ali Connors',
                subtitle: "I'll be in your neighborhood doing errands this weekend. Do you want to hang out?"
            },
            {
                action: '2 hr',
                headline: 'Summer BBQ',
                title: 'me, Scrott, Jennifer',
                subtitle: "Wish I could come, but I'm out of town this weekend."
            },
            {
                action: '6 hr',
                headline: 'Oui oui',
                title: 'Sandra Adams',
                subtitle: 'Do you have Paris recommendations? Have you ever been?'
            },
            {
                action: '12 hr',
                headline: 'Birthday gift',
                title: 'Trevor Hansen',
                subtitle: 'Have any ideas about what we should get Heidi for her birthday?'
            },
            {
                action: '18hr',
                headline: 'Recipe to try',
                title: 'Britta Holt',
                subtitle: 'We should eat this: Grate, Squash, Corn, and tomatillo Tacos.'
            }
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        filteredItems() {
            return _.orderBy(this.items.filter(item => {
                return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
                    item.action.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
                    item.headline.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
                    item.subtitle.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
            }), 'headline');
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggle(index) {
            const i = this.selected.indexOf(index)

            if (i > -1) {
                this.selected.splice(i, 1)
            } else {
                this.selected.push(index)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks but the `| orderBy 'title'` seems not work anymore in VueJS 2. What would you recommend for VueJS 2?

Comment: Yes. You right. I almost forget. You should order your list within your computed property by using loadash (_). And also you should remove `| orderBy 'title'` from your template. Something like this:   `return _.orderBy(item.title.includes(this.search), 'title')`

Comment: Thank you, works great but how to reset the search from a button? I updated your example Pen with a **clearable** option for the textfield: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEaBzX How to show all entries after clicking it?

Comment: You should handle clear button event manualy. I've editted my [example](https://codepen.io/prc0mputing/pen/qMBLNr?editors=0011)

Answer (score 6):

This might not be the standard way but you could also try like this...

Filter the input in the search first by adding a v-model `search` and an array `searchItem`. You also need to initialized `searchItem` in the *mounted* hook. Then create a *computed property* `filteredItems`. I've used [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for flexibility if you will use regex and it returns an array.

But you could also use [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) it depends on your choice

**HTML (changes)**

```
<v-toolbar>
   <v-text-field
     v-model="search" //add this
     ...
   ></v-text-field>
</v-toolbar>

<v-list two-line>
  <template v-for="(item, index) in filteredItems"> //change items to filteredItems
   ...
  </template>
</v-list>
```

**JS:**

```
data () {
  return {
    search: '',
    selected: [2],
    searchItem: [],
    items: [
       // your items here
    ]
  }
},

mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => this.searchItem = this.items)
},

computed: {
 filteredItems() {
    return this.searchItem.filter((item) =>{
         return item.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search)  || 
                item.headline.toLowerCase().match(this.search) || 
                item.subtitle.toLowerCase().match(this.search) || 
                item.action.toLowerCase().match(this.search)
    })
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

Your updated Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYwBXj?editors=1010#0)

Comment: Thank you but I get this error: **Arrow function should not return assignment**   
 for this: `setTimeout(() => this.searchItem = this.items)`  What needs to be changed?

Comment: you could just use normal setTimeout() function or let it be `this.searchItem = this.items`

Comment: Did you check the codepen? It's working fine there even when I tried in my PC.

Comment: I guess it because of "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1" or  "eslint": "^4.9.0" in my setup?